# Criando Projeto Grails no Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

Estou com problemas para criar um projeto Grails no Intellij.
Tentei com várias versões, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.6 e todas ocorrem o mesmo erro ao enviar o comando run-app:

> |Running Grails application
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : F:\Projetos\Grails\grails-2.5.0\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   agent library failed to init: instrument
>   Error |
>   Forked Grails VM exited with error

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar ocorrendo de errado? O

O projeto que estou criando está zerado, não tem nada, após criar executo esse comando e recebe esse erro. Estou usando java 1.8.

Comment: Qual versao do IntelliJ voce esta utilizando? Algumas versoes do IntelliJ nao sao compativeis com algumas versoes do Grails. Ja passei por este problema, e por incrivel que pareca ( ate estranho se falar ) hoje o NetBeans da um grande suprote para Grails. Me informe aqui qual seu IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você instalou o Grails? Eu recomendo instalar conforme:
https://vaidegrails.com/2016/05/14/como-instalar-o-grails/

Aqui a gente usa o Grails 2.5.1 com o OpenJDK 8 e funciona bem. Também já testamos com o SDK da Oracle, e roda tranquilo.